# Regular expression - remove poly() from formula

Tags: r, regex, formula

I have a formula in R as character vector, and I need to remove `poly()` from this formula, if present.

Example, and some of my (not successfull) tries so far:

```r
p <- "(.*)poly\\((\\w.*)(.*)(\\))(.*)"
unique(sub(p, "\\1", "mined + poly(cover, 3) + spp"))
#> [1] "mined + "
unique(sub(p, "\\2", "mined + poly(cover, 3) + spp"))
#> [1] "cover, 3"
unique(sub(p, "\\3", "mined + poly(cover, 3) + spp"))
#> [1] ""
unique(sub(p, "\\4", "mined + poly(cover, 3) + spp"))
#> [1] ")"
unique(sub(p, "\\5", "mined + poly(cover, 3) + spp"))
#> [1] " + spp"
```

My desired result:

Input: `"mined + poly(cover, 3) + spp"`

Output: `"mined + cover + spp"`

I have tried so many patterns, but either `poly( ..., 3)` was not removed, or `, 3)` or `, 3` remained in the resulting string... Any help is appreciated! (btw, the `3` is arbitrary, the pattern should remove any degree-value...)

Comment: Try `gsub("\\bpoly\\(\\s*(\\w+)(?:\\s*,[^)]*)?\\)", "\\1", x)`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/udXFb9/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
poly\(([^,]*)[^)]*\)
```

Replace the match with Group 1 contents

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTPjW5/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `poly\(` - matches `poly(`
- `([^,]*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `,`. This is captured in Group 1
- `[^)]*\)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `)` followed by `)`

Now replace the whole match with Group 1 contents

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("poly\\((.+),\\s*\\d+\\)", "\\1", inp)
# [1] "mined + cover + spp"
```

Or in a more tractable step-wise manner (since you are struggling with more complex regex):

```
library(magrittr)
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", inp) %>% # Drop everything that is not a letter, add space instead
  gsub("poly", "", .) %>%       # Drop the word poly 
  gsub("\\s+", " + ", .)        # Add '+' back in. '\\s+' stands for one or more spaces
# [1] "mined + cover + spp"
```